# TeamCity SVN externals different credentials

Tags: svn, continuous-integration, teamcity, svn-externals

I got a project in TeamCity 7.1.1 for which I defined a VCS root.
The VCS root is an external SVN server from which I would like to checkout. The project in the repository contains an svn:external to our internal SVN server.

The credentials for the external SVN server are different than the credentials for the internal server. This means that I can not set "Externals support" to "Full support".

The TeamCity documentation states that I should use the same password or should not use a password at all for my externals. This isn't the best option.

Is there a way to configure that for a specific repository a specific set of credentials is used always? Or any other workaround? Thanks!

Comment: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-24284

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the question in the issuetracker of TeamCity and got an answer: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-24284

Comment: Logging into the build server and forcing a checkout of external and saving SVN credentials worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

While TeamCity may not support this directly, you could use multiple VCS Roots as a workaround.

If you define a VCS root for the main project, and another VCS root for the external, you could provide different credentials for the external.

You could use the [VCS Checkout Rules](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/VCS+Checkout+Rules) in TeamCity to place the checked out folders where you need them in your project structure.

Note, you may need to exclude the externals from the first root since they would fail authentication.